# The sum $\sum_{k=0}^n k \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-k} \binom nk$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-k} {n\choose k}$$

Is there a specific way to solve this exercise? (how to start or the basic idea of a solution at exercises like this one).

Comment: The binomial theorem states $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}ka^{n-k}b^k.$$

Comment: The k is your problem. You get rid of it when you open the n over k, and rearrange it so that it becomes the binomial theorem thing for a different n.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating both sides of 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k = (1+x)^n$$
with respect to $x$ yields
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} x^{k-1} = n(1+x)^{n-1},$$
so
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} x^k = nx(1+x)^{n-1}.$$
Now
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-k}
= \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k
= \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n n\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1} 
= \frac{n}{3}.$$
Alternatively, recognize your sum as the expected number of successes from $n$ samples of a $\text{Bernoulli}(1/3)$ random variable.  By linearity of expectation, this is $$n\cdot \mathbb{E}[\text{Bernoulli}(1/3)] = n\cdot (1/3)= n/3.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $k\ge1,$ $$k\binom nk=\cdots=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Set $k-1=r$ to find

$$n\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1} a^kb^{n-k}=na\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}a^rb^{n-1-r}=na(a+b)^{n-1}$$

Can you recognize $a,b$ here?